# xml2js, attribute name contains a hyphen

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using xml2js to parse an XML file, I need to retrieve the value of an attribute which contains a hyphen in its name

```
<item cdr-id="1234">
    <name>some text</name>
</item>
```

At the point where I'm trying to retrieve `cdr-id`, I already have a variable `item` which points to the item element.  I've verified it's pointing to the proper node with

```
console.log(item.name);
```

and that returns the expected value `some text`. But when I try

```
console.log(item.$.cdr-id);
```

I get the completely reasonable error `ReferenceError: id is not defined` (I'd have been more surprised if `id` wasn't treated as a separate token).

Likewise,

```
console.log(item.$."cdr-id");
```

gets the message `SyntaxError: Unexpected string`.

Throwing JSON.stringify around it

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(item.$));
```

reveals the original attribute name: `{"cdr-id":"CDR0000040222"}`

Not having hyphens in the name in the first place just kicks the problem down the road a bit. Failing that, it looks like providing a custom attribute name processor is the way to go, but that smacks of being "too clever" with potential for confusion if anyone ever has to update this code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
console.log(item.$["cdr-id"]);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. I *really* didn't want to rewrite the attribute name.